# Comparing vectors of multiple column values in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the following example:

```
DT <- data.table(A1=c(1,2),A2=c(2,3),B1=c(1,2),B2=c(3,4),B3=c(2,5))
```

I want to check for each row whether the value in column A1 and A2 both occur in either B1, B2 or B3.

If I do:

```
DT[,BOTH_PRESENT:=!(F %in% (c(A1,A2) %in% c(B1,B2,B3)))]
```

This yields:

```
   A1 A2 B1 B2 B3 BOTH_PRESENT
1:  1  2  1  3  2         TRUE
2:  2  3  2  4  5         TRUE
```

While I would expect True for the 1st row and False for the 2nd row.

```
# Row 1
!(F %in% (c(1,2) %in% c(1,3,2)))
# Row 2
!(F %in% (c(2,3) %in% c(2,4,5)))
```

How should I change my code?

Since my real dataset is much larger in terms of columns making expressions like `(A1 == B1 | A1 == B2 | A1 == B3) & (A2 == B1 | A2 == B2 | A2 == B3)`  won't be a nice solution.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please provide feedback if you do so..

Comment: I think the solution in the end is actually quite efficient. You only have to create the expression programmatically if you have many columns.

Comment: Alright, will try, thanks

Comment: Can the same value show up in multiple B columns, like 1 3 3 instead of 1 3 2 in the first row?

Comment: No, the values refer to unique items in a shopping basket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can group by the sequence of rows of the data.table, `unlist` the 'A', columns, check whether `all` those elements are `%in%` the `unlist`ed 'B' columns.

```
 DT[, BOTH_PRESENT := all(unlist(.SD[, 1:2, with = FALSE]) %in% 
        unlist(.SD[, 3:5, with = FALSE])), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

Or as @Roland mentioned,

```
 DT[,BOTH_PRESENT:= all(c(A1, A2) %in% c(B1,B2,B3)), by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]
```

Comment: Or `DT[,BOTH_PRESENT:= all(c(A1, A2) %in% c(B1,B2,B3)), by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]`. Bot note that this is a loop iterating over the rows, which might be slow.

Comment: Thanks, will try, actually need to perform this check while grouping on A1 and A2 to calculate an aggregate measure, but I think I can rewrite your code to do just that

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys, works like a charm. I prefer @Roland 's solution in the comment (more readable).